# XBee on Arduino Fio - how to read the status of a local digital XBee output pin?

Tags: xbee

I am using a Fio to control a set of relays. The unit uses an XBee (series 1 Pro) in transparent mode to receive commands over serial UART and everything works fine. The XBee is also configured for digital Input/Output Line Passing and the XBee on the Fio "mirrors" on an output pin the input state on a remote XBee and also this works fine.

How can I interrogate from the Fio the state of the output pin (e.g. D0) of the local (receiving) XBee? Is there an AT command that I could send via `Serial.println("ATxx")` that would trigger the XBee to send back over UART the status of the pin (high or low)?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read the state of output pins via an AT command, you can only read the state of input pins using the ATIS command.

See: http://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/90000982_S.pdf